# Docker fails to build in Azure Pipelines with "error MSB1001"

Tags: asp.net, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

Am facing strange issue. When i build my `Dockerfile` on windows machine(Laptop) getting below error and also getting same error when i tried to deploy on `Azure DevOps`.

```
Step 7/17 : COPY ["WebApp.csproj", ""]
 ---> 3f3e198d00aa
Step 8/17 : RUN dotnet restore "/WebApp.csproj"
 ---> Running in 51f16f947ffb
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /WebApp.csproj

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "/WebApp.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Directory>
```

But the same `Dockerfile` works fine when we build it using **visual studio** it builds and starts running without any errors.

Docker file looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApp.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "/WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

Comment: What do you mean "on windows machine" (using visual studio is not on windows?)?

Comment: I mean on my computer.

Comment: And it fails on Azure-Pipelines?

Comment: yes the same error on local as well. But when i run it from visual studio it builds and runs the application

Comment: in the `dotent restore` try to remove the `/` (only `"WebApp,csproj"`)

Comment: Great! I added it also as an answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because in your `dotnet restore` there is `/` so MSBuild think it's a switch (like `/p:`) and fails, you just need to remove it:

```
RUN dotnet restore "WebApp.csproj"
```